# Different Bootstrap themes on vendor vs client facing admin dashboards

Tags: dashboard, administration

I'm creating a multi-tenant web application. We (the vendor) are developing an application where each organization that subscribes will have its own administration dashboard.

The "client facing" admin dashboard is themed using Bootstrap 4 and a commercial Bootstrap template which looks nice. However, our "vendor" dashboard will be *much* simpler and is mostly just a UI to add/remove organizations and change some settings. The rest of the administration would be done by logging into one of the organization's admin dashboards with escalated privileges.

My concern is continuity. Vendor administrators (i.e. people in my company) might have a poor user experience while managing clients if the page layout and theme keeps changing when switching to our admin panel to the client admin panel and vice versa.

On the other hand, in my opinion having two different styles makes it clear and obvious which system your currently working in. It would also save some costs not having to use a commercial theme which only our company would be viewing.

Any thoughts on this? Is there recommendations against having two different styles/layouts?

Comment: The differences may or may not be significant. Screenshots to illustrate the separate interfaces would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How about utilizing the same theme and layout but add some nuances to the admin dashboard such as a different color tone? It'll be sufficiently similar that you won't have to bother "familiarizing" yourself with two different layouts (it will be easier/cheaper to maintain also), but different enough that you're less likely to commit mistakes from thinking you're tinkering on the wrong side.